# Drawig Graphics in Windows Forms Application C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

Hello guys I need some help to draw the graphic in Windows Forms Application.

I downloaded Nevron Chart for .NET Community Edition from here:

https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-chart-free-control

And I drag one chart from tools in Windows Forms Application

So I make connection in the chart with MySql but I need to export the query in the chart.

My Code is:

```
private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string MyConString3 = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=hydrodb;" +
                "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;";
    MySqlConnection connection3 = new MySqlConnection(MyConString3);

    string command3 = "select year(Dat),month(Dat),min(vkolmin),avg(Vkolsre),Max(Vkolmax) from hydmes where station='"
        + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and Dat between '"
        + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()
        + "' group by year(dat),month(Dat)";
        MySqlDataAdapter da3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command3, connection3);
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        da3.Fill(dt3);

        string s = "";
        foreach (DataRow row in dt3.Rows) {
            string rowz = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2],
            row.ItemArray[3], row.ItemArray[4]);
            s += "-" + rowz;
        }
        connection3.Close();
    }
```

I'm not sure if I need foreach ?

I need to export this query from

```
string command3 = "select year(Dat),month(Dat),min(vkolmin),avg(Vkolsre),Max(Vkolmax) from hydmes where station='"
    + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and Dat between '"
    + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()
    + "' group by year(dat),month(Dat)";`
```

In the chart ?

Some help with the code ?

Comment: This is not clear, what are you doing with the Rows in `dt3`?  you need to export the query in the chart, just the chart graphics or the SQL aswell? and where are you assigning the charts datasource?

Comment: Can you give me the example code, please ?

Comment: This is my string for db, string MyConString3 = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                "DATABASE=hydrodb;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=;";

Comment: Your title seems quite misleading. All you are looking for is feeding data from a query to Nevron Chart, right? Please correct the title and the tags!

Comment: lol dude, I have asked you 3 things to clarify your question, you didn't answer any and respond with **Plz give me teh codez!**

Comment: This application contains water quantities calculated to be displayed in graph

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to draw graphics in winform, why not use the zedgraph instead. They have got lots of sample codes for many varieties of charts as well..

Do checkout the following links :

[1. Samples From Code project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/5431/a-flexible-charting-library-for-net)

[2. The Official Site containing sample materials](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I dont like zedgraph :)